# How to convert sine wave form in to audio?

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, sine-wave

I have raw data:

**x-values
y-values**

`x` being the time domain. Sample rate is 8000 Hz.

I have plotted them in a sine wave, but can't seem to find any way to convert that into audio form.

Can someone guide through this process?

Comment: Please, specify what are `x`, `y`  and also specify their types, so I can expand my answer.

Comment: x is time domain and y is frequency, we have sampled it at 8000hz.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer. And how is encoded your raw data?

Comment: we have e encoded it into PCM format in the android studio and taken the x and y values through the code in android. Now we are plotting it in MATLAB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `x` is the time domain, you don't really need it since you have `Fs` = 8000 Hz.

`y` is your data, you can try to use [`audiowrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiowrite.html) to convert it to an audiofile.

We don't know exactly how your data is encoded, so you will probably need to do some work.

For example, it could be

```
audiowrite('audioFile.wav`, y, Fs);
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it done but I have used 1000 values from y as it's clear x is of no use here so it made a file of 1 second. I want it sound longer.

Comment: @SaifAli If you have 1000 values at 8000 Hz it should last 1/8 second I don't know how you made it last 1 second. Anyway, if you want to increase the duration of the audio file you can: 1. get more data, 2. repeat your data any time you want `y = [y; y; y; y]`, 3. reduce `Fs` (but you will also change the pitch of your sound).